# Invocation message while running gdb

Tags: c, gdb

Why does it give me this when i try to run in gdb ?

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home//Cfile/./ginr 
Invocation:  /home/Cfile/./ginr <test case file> <results file> [-repeat]
[Inferior 1 (process 3615) exited with code 01]
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-222.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a message from the program itself. If you try to run `/home/Cfile/./ginr` in a terminal without arguments you probably get the same results.

You need to provide arguments when running the program, which is done almost the same inside `gdb`:

```
(gdb) run test_case_file result_File
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the debuginfo package.  How you do that depends on your OS, which you haven't listed here, which would have made your question much clearer and much easier to answer.

Furthermore - this would be easily discovered with a simple google search, so you should try that before putting a question up here.  The key was to search for the error message at the bottom "Missing separate debuginfos" which, incidentally, isn't really an 'invocation error'.  If you searched for that and didn't actually find an answer, it would probably have made sense to include some portion of that error in your question title.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: As an example to the solution you would use for RedHat Linux:   https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1506273